# pdf google maps export

Tags: geoserver, google, maps, pdf, layers

In my php+postgis+geoserver+OL application I have to export a map in a pdf file. 
This map has two layer: the base is a google map layer and a vector layer as overlay. 
Is there a way to make a pdf like this?

Comment: It sounds like this is more of a GeoServer question - how to export a pdf from a GeoServer application - is that so?

Comment: If your application runs in a web browser, can you issue a print-to-pdf?

Comment: Just as an incomplete suggestion: try [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). I'm using it to grab a png capture of google maps.